# How to use a .exe file to run commands in command prompt

Tags: windows, console-application

I do **NOT** want to run a .exe from the command prompt. 
I want to run a command, lets say its `taskkill /IM "chrome" /F.` Can I save this as a .exe (or any other extension) to my desktop so that when i open/run that file it will act as though I've typed it into command prompt? 
Sorry if this is offtopic, when i googled it just brought up run a .exe from command prompt (Again **not what i want to do**) ect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file named `kill_chrome.cmd`

Enter the following:

```
taskkill /IM /F chrome
```

Save the file or a shortcut to the file to your desktop.

Click, run, and profit.